# Defender Right Indicator Incorrectly Canceling while Turning Right

Tags: electronics, land-rover

*2000 Land Rover Defender 90 Td5*

While indicating right and turning the steering wheel right the indicator cancels where it should latch waiting for the wheel to turn back left to the center position.

This does problem does not present itself when turning left.

I have replaced the part (needed to because of a broken full beam latch anyway) but the problem persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Troubleshooting:

- Pull out the rubber seal between the indicator stalk and the housing for the steering column and stalks.

If this fixes the problem that means that the rubber is pulling down the indicator stalk when indicating right, and when the click from the latching mechanism vibrates the stalk it wiggles loose.

The fix for this is to bend the arm of the indicator stalk down slightly, or just leave the rubber loose. This may also be caused by an incorrect installation of the housing, so it may be worth removeing and re-installing that.

- Park with the wheels straight on, remove the steering wheel.

If the blue collar surrounding the steering column's arrow is pointing away from the indicator stalk turn it around until it faces it and re-install the steering wheel.